# Extract all properties and values from entities from a large set of heterogeneous RDF datasets

Tags: semantic-web, linked-data

I would like to know if there exists some work that is able to extract all properties and values from entities from a large set of heterogeneous RDF datasets, such as [LOD cloud](https://lod-cloud.net/)?

**Example**: I would like to extract all properties and values from all **cities** from all datasets of the whole [LOD cloud](https://lod-cloud.net/).

**Problem**: Ontology alignment, example, city in [DBpedia](https://dbpedia.org) is represented by (http://dbpedia.org/ontology/City) but [wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org), city is (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q515).

Answer (score 0):

Written on the website https://lod-cloud.net/#about

> The raw data is available [here](https://lod-cloud.net/lod-data.json)

You got downvotes because SO is not a place for questions with no research or thinking, otherwise, we'd be spammed with thoughtless questions.

---

### Answering comment

The ontologies have to be merged, maybe define it with `owl:equivalentClass` `owl:sameAs`. 
http://schema.org is a project already established attempting to solve the problem, so to have a master ontology once for all.

[Geospatial Consortium](http://www.opengeospatial.org/) also tries to standardize geo terms.

There is also data mining research about merging data (including ontology), which I don't know enough to give exact advice.

Comment: **Thank you for the answer**.
---
How did you solve the problem of the ontology matching in all these heterogeneous datasets from LODcloud, because they do not follow the same ontology.
---
How to answer a simple question, such as " how to extract all properties and values from all cities from all datasets"
---
Remember, we are talking about different datasets, with different ontologies.
---
Example: example, city in DBpedia is represented by (http://dbpedia.org/ontology/City) but wikidata, city is (https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q515) and so on...
---
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've updated my answer for the second question. You may want to update your question to be clearer, so more ppl may consider answering.